# Removing elements from enum, cascading to null if possible

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update an enum type that I have through a migration, but I'm running into an error. Here's what I have:

```
create type enum_level_type as enum (
  'level_0',
  'level_1',
  'level_2'
);
create table levels (
  id serial primary key,
  level enum_level_type
);
```

```
insert into levels values
  (1, 'level_0'),
  (2, 'level_1'),
  (3, 'level_1'),
  (4, 'level_2');
```

```
alter type enum_level_type rename to enum_level_type_old;
create type enum_level_type as enum (
  'level_0',
  'level_1'
);
alter table levels
  alter "level" set data type enum_level_type,
  alter "level" set not null;

drop type enum_level_type_old;
```

This throws an error,

```
column "level" cannot be cast automatically to type enum_level_type
```

Ideally, I'd like to keep these records with their original value. So, in this case, I try to remove `level_2` from `enum_level_type`, but I'd like to keep the record with `id = 4`.

If that isn't possible, I'd like to cascade `'level_2' -> null`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't get what you want. You say that you don't want a value `level_2` in your enum, that you want the column to be `not null`, and that you also want to keep that row that would violate either of those constraints. You can't have all three.

Comment: I need to it from the enum for a migration, but there are existing records in the table. What would be the best way to approach this, then?

Comment: What migration, why do you need to remove it? And you need to decide yourself what should happen to the existing records in the table that use the value, we can't tell you what's best in your case.

Comment: keep them as a value that does not exist anymore - how can that work?   set them null but add a not null constraint - how can that work?

Comment: Lesson learned: never use an `enum` if a label could be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest is probably

```
alter table levels
  alter "level" set data type enum_level_type USING
    case when "level" <> 'level_2' then "level"::text::enum_level_type end;
```

The double cast `::text::enum_level_type`  tells postgresql to use values from the new type that match the name of the values from the old type. without that hint it would consider them to be incompatible types.

This gets you a null where there was `level_2`.

```
jasen=# select * from levels order by id;
 id |  level  
----+---------
  1 | level_0
  2 | level_1
  3 | level_1
  4 | 
(4 rows)
```